# mpeg-dash with live stream

Tags: mpeg-dash, mp4box

I would like to use MPEG-DASH technology in situations where I am constantly receiving a live video stream from a client. The Web server gets a live video stream, keeps generating the m4s file, and declares it in mpd. So the new segment can be played back constantly.
(I'm using FFMPEG's ffserver. So the video stream continues to accumulate in /tmp/feed1.ffm file.)

Using MP4Box seems to be able to generate mpd, init.mp4, m4s for already existing files. But it does not seem to support live streaming.

I want fragmented mp4 in segment format rather than mpeg-ts.

A lot of advice is needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPAC maintainer here. The dashcast project (and likely its dashcastx replacement from our [Signals platform](https://github.com/gpac/signals) should help you). Please open issues on github if you have any issues.

Please note that there are some projects like [this one](https://github.com/gpac/test-engine-live-tools) using FFmpeg to generate some HLS and then GPAC to ingest the TS segments to produce MPEG-DASH. This introduces some latency but proved to be very robust.

Answer (score 2):

Below information may be useful.

latest ffmpeg supports the live streaming and also mp4 fragmenting.
Example command

```
ffmpeg -re -y -i <input> -c copy -f dash -window_size 10 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 <ClearLive>.mpd
```